# Hibernate Criteria Api does not provide accurate result list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

I am having two tables in database USER_DETAILS and Address. The Entity classes for both the tables are below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {`

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int UserID;
private String UserName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Address> address=new ArrayList<>();

-------------------------------------------------------------
@Entity
public class Address {

@Id @Column(name="ADD_ID") @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;
private String street;
private String city;
```

I want to execute a query such that it return me all the results where UserName="user1" and
 address.city='City1'
When i execute the sql query as

```
SELECT u.UserName,a.street
from USER_DETAILS u, Address a
where u.UserName='user1'
and a.city='City1';
```

The result is

```
+----------+---------+
| UserName | street  |
+----------+---------+
| user1    | street1 |
+----------+---------+
```

But when I run a criteria query for the above as

```
 Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(UserDetails.class,"user")
                        .createAlias("address", "ad")
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("user.UserName", "user1"))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("ad.street", "street2"));
```

The result it shows is completely different than expected which is

```
user1
City2 :: street2
City6 :: street6
City4 :: street4
City8 :: street8
City0 :: street0
```

I tried other options like `createQuery("Address")` instead of `createAlias()`. but the results where same. Please give your suggestions.

Thank you

EDIT: I used HQl query similar to one i used as sql as

```
List<Object[]> list=session.createQuery("select u.UserName,a.street "
        +" from UserDetails u,Address a"
        + " where u.UserName=:username and a.city=:cityname")
        .setString("username", "user1")
        .setString("cityname", "City1")
        .list();
```

I got the same result as in sql which is the correct one. But criteria does not show the correct result.

Comment: Your first query doesn't have a join between user and address. Your second query has one, and returns all the users named "user1" and having at least one address with street=street2. That doesn't mean these users don't have other addresses. I guess (because you didn't post the cde), that that's what you're printing: the users returned by the query, and the addresses of the users returned by the query.

Comment: I did not get you. Would you clearify a little with the code. please

Comment: Let's say I ask "who knows Java?" You will answer "I do". Does that mean that the only thing you know is Java? No, it doesn't. If, after that, I ask you "tell me all you know", you'll answer Java, C, Football, English, ... The same happens here. You're executing a query asking "who is named user1 and has an address with street2". One user is returned. And then you're printing the user's name and the whole list of his addresses.

Comment: Also, neither the SQL query nor the HQL query at the end makes sure that the user1 returned has the street1 in any of his addresses. You're just making a cross product of the two tables (all the combinations of user and address), and only take the combinations having user 1 as the name and street1 as the street. You need a join between the two tables/entities.

Answer (score 0):

Something as below

**HQL/SQL**

```
SELECT u.UserName,a.street
from USER_DETAILS u 
inner join u.Address ua
where u.UserName='user1'
and ua.city='City1';
```

**Criteria API**

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(UserDetails.class, "u");
c.createAlias("user.Address", "ua");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("u.UserName", "user1")
c.add(Restrictions.eq("ua.city", "City1");
```

Have a look here for more [info](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/CriteriaOneToManyAssociationsCriteria.htm).